# Mediaelement.js Need to custom remove the Duration off the Audio

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using the MediaElements.js HTML 5 video/audio plugin mainly for the Audio right now.

I would like to customize the look so it's simply a 30x30 play button (which I know how to do) and the Duration, controls, everything else is removed.

So JUST the box with the Play button and nothing else.

how would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't tell which way you are embedding the player (there are several ways to do it), but the easiest way to customize the player is by adding the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('video').mediaelementplayer({
            features: ['playpause'],
        });
    });
</script>
```

Right now this will target only the `<video>` tag, but if you are using the `<audio>` tag the code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
              features: ['playpause'],
        });
    });
</script>
```

The settings are located where it says "features." You can list the different controls that you want. These are as follows:

```
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'],
```

Just list each one with quotations around it, and separate them with commas (except for the last one). I hope this helps!